# fkeys on Pi4 using Mac alumium extended keyboard not working

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, keyboard

I am using a Mac Aluminium extended keyboard with a Pi4. It's there as an option in Raspian Prefs - which I have set to ISO.
In the one app I am using that has the option of f1 thru f6 to move between data entry fields the fkeys are not working. Is there a way of controlling this? I am guessing it's not application specific and relates the way the OS reads the keyboard.

Comment: Have you tried setting the function keys to act as a normal key where you need to press the fn-key to change volume etc.?  It’s in the Mac OS system preferences for keyboard.  My Mac is packed away at the mo else I would be a bit more clear...

Comment: Just to reiterate:
I am using the keyboard on a Pi4 running raspian OS. 
I know how to use the fkeys on a Mac.

Comment: Apologies - I had assumed you where using SSH from the Mac.  In this case I think you may need to investigate the xmodmap functionality.